# Python open TortoiseSVN SVN log popup window for a repository

Tags: python, windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have TortoiseSVN installed in my windows machine. Using the command line operation I am able to get the svn log data for a repository. but I want to open the "svn show log" popup window for the repository instead of this method. using python I wanna invoke the svn show log popup for a repository. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Attached an image of what I am able to achieve, vs what I need.
Note: Data hidden for confidentiality purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate TortoiseSVN UI using [`TortoiseProc.exe` with the `/command:log` option.](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-1-table) Here is an example:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/
```

Comment: I have tried ur command on the windows terminal I get a error popup saying Neither path or pathfile specified on the command

Comment: A colon is missing between /path and the svn path. the correct command that worked is `TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/`

Comment: @SuryaTej thanks for noticing that. BTW, when I use URL in after `/path` without colon it works too.